# How do I create a static page and redirect to a WordPress blog without moving files?

Tags: wordpress

I have WordPress installed in the main directory. I want to create a static page so that when the person clicks "click here". It goes to the wordpress blog.

I have tried this two ways thus far.

1. Created a custom page in wordpress and then had it set as a static page. Problem when someone clicked the linked it redirected back to the splash page.
2. Put the files in the main directory. Problem the person would have to go to www.example.com/splash.html to get there. I tried creating a htaccess but host gator will not let me.

edit: I figured it out using

```
<?php
  if( (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], get_bloginfo('home')) === false) && !$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) :
?>
```

Comment: Please post the solution so others with the same problem can find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the splash page if its just one link on it?

One option is to create your page within wordpress and set the frontpage to show as a static page (under settings > reading). On that page link to your /blog/ category or to a custom template page that displays all your blog posts.

If you want to have the same design as the page currently has, you can make a new template out of you current index.php file.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

The simple option is to use a plugin.

http://cochinoman.com/2009/02/16/wordpress-plugin-for-splash-screen/

Gives you the option to Continue on or go back.